# How to substitute TF2 prefix

Tags: ros, tf2-ros, tf2, tf-prefix, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have seen that tf_prefix support is deprecated in TF2. What is the proper way now of having the same functionality? That is, I have two robots, robot1 and robot2, and I want the TF frames to append these names to their corresponding `base_link`s. How should I properly do it?

EDIT: Also, what is the meaning then of the `tf_prefix` parameter of the `robot_state_publisher` node? Is that the way to proceed with all the other nodes using TF frames (parameters and manually concatenating in the nodes)?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220104/how-to-substitute-tf2-prefix/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-10-29

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Despite the *deprecation* warning, `tf_prefix` still works and there is still no alternative solution.

My guess is that ROS 1 will continue to support `tf_prefix` indefinitely, but we should ask for an opinion from @tfoote about that.

The deprecation may happen in ROS 2, but it is still too early in that design cycle to tell.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-10-30**:
Thanks for the answer. For completeness: [tf2 migration page](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Migration) `However tf will continue to be supported for through at least J Turtle.` Actually I do not get any warning, is just me trying to do things correctly.